# libjpeg.9.dylib version update

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to finish a project and the project needs a lower version of python, so I downgraded it and now when I try to use matplot, the system shows this "Incompatible library version: _imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.9.dylib provides version 12.0.0" and I can't find the right way to upgrade this, can someone help, please?

[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: 你好，请问这个问题解决了吗，我也遇到同样的问题